# The fragment is still visible after replacing with another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments and one of them is visible by default and I used the code below for it. (all codes are in an activity that is the parent of both fragments)

```
MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,mainFragment).commit();
```

using a navigation tool user can change the visible fragment and I use this code for changing the
fragment.

```
MarketFragment marketFragment = new MarketFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, marketFragment).commit();
```

but it seems that this new fragment just appears on top of the previous one and the clicks on `main fragment` still register.

I also tried removing the `main fragment` first but it didn't change anything.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(visibleFragment).commit();
MarketFragment marketFragment = new MarketFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, marketFragment).commit();
```

I also tried `rebuild` and `invalidate cache` the project but these didn't help either.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the previous fragment is visible because you have not set a background for them. So, what you have to do is to set a background to the layout files of these fragments like this:

```xml
android:background="@color/white"
```

Or

```xml
android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
```

Comment: both fragments' roots have backgrounds and I even tried adding tint to both of them but the previous fragment still registers clicks.

Comment: Can you share the code for both the fragments?